# Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in V^{*}$ be linearly independent. Then for all $j$, there is $v_j \in \bigcap\limits_{i \neq j} \ker f_i \setminus \ker f_j$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in V^{*}$ be linearly independent. Then for all $j$, there is $v_j \in \bigcap\limits_{i \neq j} \ker f_i \setminus \ker f_j$.

What I did: As $\ker f_k$ is a hyperplane, there is $v_k \in V \setminus \ker f_k$ and $V = \ker f_k \oplus [v_k]$. Is this $v_k$ that satisfies $v_k \in \bigcap_{i \neq k} \ker f_i \setminus \ker f_k$? How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I assumed that $V$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}$.

Let $F: V \to \mathbb{K}^n$ be the linear map defined by 
                 $$F(v):=(f_1(v),\cdots,f_n(v))$$
The hypothesis on $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ to be l.i. implies that $F$ is surjective. Indeed, if $F$ were not surjective the image $F(V)$ will be contained in a hyperplane (through the origen) of $\mathbb{K}^n$ hence the $f_i$'s are l.d.

Let $e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{K}^n$ i.e. $e_1 = (1,0,\cdots,0), e_2 = (0,1,0,\cdots,0)$ and so on.

For each $j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ being $F$ surjective there is $v_j$ such that $$F(v_j) = e_j \, .$$

Then notice that that $f_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$ so $$v_j \in \cap_{i \neq j} \ker f_i \setminus \ker f_j$$